# Controller gives wrong number of arguments error when GET request is made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have written a rails-api with two resources `users` and `books`. When I make a GET request for `books` it works properly, but for `users` it fails with the following message:

```
Started GET "/users/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-18 23:45:52 +0530
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `index'


  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/rails-35ca78a07c8b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (17.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/rails-35ca78a07c8b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/rails-35ca78a07c8b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/rails-35ca78a07c8b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (69.4ms)
```

Here is the error I get on the browser:

ArgumentError in UsersController#index

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #8):

```
...       
  # GET /users
  def index        
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users # this is line 8
  end
    ...
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :books
end
```

Any clue on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Do you have an as_jason method in User.rb?

Comment: Please, put your routes.rb content.

Comment: @Diego Senott I did that.

Comment: @Swards No I do not.

Comment: In the logs, you should get better information about which file is throwing that error.  Line 8 may be the last line of code you wrote, but something in the @users instance variable is causing a problem further down the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was with my model that was being passed to the serializer. I had a column in my database with the name `method`. `method` is a rails reserved word (read: [ruby-and-rails-reserved-words](http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words)) which was creating the problem. I renamed my column to `registration_method` which fixed the issue. Thanks everyone for the help :)

Comment: I hope you didn't misspell that in your code as you did above in your answer. `registeration_method'

Answer (score 0):

could try render @users.to_json

Is User.all returning any users?

Comment: Yeah, User.all gives me the expected result.

Comment: I tried using @users.to_json. Things worked absolutely fine, but since I'm using ActiveModel::Serializer to pack my response according to JSONAPI specifications, the formatting does not happen as expected i.e. I get raw json. I'm confused about how the serializer's formatting works for the `books` resource and fails for `users`.

Comment: interesting.  some function isn't getting a parameter it expects.  So it's either the render function or a function called by it.  I'd give a try to  use
render(json: @users)
or 
render({:json => @users})  

although I doubt they would fix it.  Just trying to figure out which function it is that isn't getting the parameters it wants